# Objects getting deleted ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm using gem called paranoia to softly delete my objects, in this case model Match. This is the github url :

https://github.com/radar/paranoia

I have a situation where my objects are getting deleted and I don't know how. Good circumstance is that they're only softly deleted so I can revert it.

The reason why I'm suprised is because I don't have a delete action in my controller, and I don't have a piece of code in my model logic which would delete it.

What is the best strategy to tackle this issue? I mean I could ask for .delete in my project and go trough each of the lines to see which one is causing it, but I have about 20k lines of code and many models so it would take a while. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be look for update_attributes or any updating code and see if the deleted_at field is somehow getting set to a default value. Other than that it's hard to say without a little more context.